# Why does molar conductivity of a weak electrolyte exceed that of a strong electrolyte at low concentrations?

Tags: physical-chemistry, electrochemistry, salt

My textbook has this graph.

[image: Graph depicting molar conductivity vs concentration]

The only sort of explanation given is that conductivity increases on dilution because the salts ionise better. Which is incomplete because then the graph for KCl should be a flat line. But since strong electrolytes dissociate a 100%, you would expect it to set some sort of a limit, because that's as best as you can get in terms of dissociation, and that's the only difference between the two salts.

Comment: you should notice that is related to the mobility of the ions in solution. The molar conductivity of acetic acid can be expressed as $\Lambda_m^0(\ce{CH3OOH}) = \lambda(\ce{CH3OO^-}) + \lambda(\ce{H^+})$. If you check a table of limiting molar conductivites you would notice that the conductivity of \ce{H^+} and \ce{OH-} is much larger than other ions.

Comment: @PAEP tough day? You missed a carbon atom in acetic acid.

Comment: @PAEP okay, but what about weak electrolytes that do not have H+ or OH- ions? Do their conductivities not exceed those of regular ionic salts?

Comment: @Nikunj Mundhra I am not sure that I understand your question. In aqueous solution, the molar ionic conductivities of the ions are much smaller than those 
of $\rm{H^+}$ or $\rm{OH^-}$ since their mobility is explained with a different mechanism than that other ions. As an educated guess I would not expect 
to observe the kind of behaviour you illustrated for \ce{KCl} when compared to \ce{CH3COOH} molar conductivities.

Comment: You could find the Wikipedia page on _molar conductivity_ (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molar_conductivity) useful. I would recommend you to check a Physical Chemistry (Electrochemistry) textbook.

Comment: @PAEP what i meant was if you have a weak electrolyte that does not have an H+ or OH- ions, their conductivities should not exceed those of strong electrolytes such as KCl. So the generalization of the graph breaks down. Also thanks, I will check the wiki out.

Comment: @Nikunj Mundhra  I would say that an electrolyte has \ce{H^+} or \{OH^-} ions is not correct. I think that a more accurate description is that upon dissolution it generates \ce{H^+} or \ce{OH-} ions as in the case of \ce{CH3COOH}.  For electrolytes that do not generate those ions ... I guess you would expect a linear dependence with $\sqrt{c}$.

Comment: @PAEP Oh I'm sorry for the inaccuracy, I'm just a high schooler and that's how I had it in my head, thanks for correcting me. Also yeah that's what I'd been suspecting as well.